# Как правильно выполнить POST запрос в функции post с передачей параметра из текстового поля

Tags: python, tkinter

Подскажите как правильно написать в запросе.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


def clicked():
    res = f"Отправлено на номер"
    lbl.configure(text=res)



def send():
    clicked()
    post()



def post():
    url = 'https://bsms.tele2.ru/api/send?operation=send&login=&password=&msisdn=msisdn&shortcode=inpk&text=https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html'
    msisdn = txt.get()

window = Tk()
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")
window.geometry('400x250')
lbl = Label(window, text="Введите номер телефона c 7")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = Entry(window, width=10)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
txt.focus()
btn = Button(window, text="Отправить ссылку!", command=send)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Полностью зависит от того, что конкретно вы хотите написать.

Comment: Необходимо отправлять сообщения, по url.

Comment: Ну, судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу, похоже что нужно делать POST запрос, например с помощью requests.post, вы пробовали это делать?

Comment: Тут вы не выполняете никакой запрос, вы просто заполняете переменные. В этой же функции ниже этих строк нужно добавить `requests.post` с нужными параметрами.

Comment: r = requests.post(url, msisdn)  так?

Comment: Не знаю, я не в курсе что там у теле2 за API. Вам должно быть виднее, раз в с этим API уже работали.

Comment: вопрос в том как этот запрос вставить в функцию

Comment: Точно так же, как любую строку вставляете в функцию. Добавляете ниже имеющихся в функции строк с таким же отступом.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда подскажите пожалуйста как вынести правильно вынести msisdn, чтобы брать его из переменной.

Comment: Это можно сделать через форматирование строк, например через f-строки или метод format. Еще лучше - передавать все что у вас в прямо в url вшито как словарь через параметр params: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо, допустим, вы отправляете запрос как

```
r = requests.post(
'https://bsms.tele2.ru/api/send?operation=send&login=&password=msisdn=msisdn&shortcode'
'=inpk&text=https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html')
```

И вы спрашиваете, как это сделать более правильно, и как передать туда параметр `msisdn`, полученный из текстового поля.

Все параметры, которые идут внутри url после `?` имеет смысл вынести в словарь и передавать их через `params` ([документация](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)):

```
params = dict(
    operation="send",
    login=".....",
    password=".....",
    msisdn=txt.get(),
    shortcode="inpk",
    text="https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html",
)

# Это аналогично такому словарю,
# но через dict легче читается и меньше раз нужно нажимать кавычку:
# params = {
#     'operation': 'send',
#     'login': '.....',
#     'password': '.....',
#     'msisdn': txt.get(),
#     'shortcode': 'inpk',
#     'text': 'https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html'
# }

r = requests.post("https://bsms.tele2.ru/api/send", params=params)
```

Ну и соответственно добавляете это в вашу функцию post:

```
def post():
    params = dict(
        operation="send",
        login=".....",
        password=".....",
        msisdn=txt.get(),
        shortcode="inpk",
        text="https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html",
    )

    r = requests.post("https://bsms.tele2.ru/api/send", params=params)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.post(
'https://bsms.tele2.ru/api/send?operation=send&login=&password=msisdn=msisdn&shortcode'
'=inpk&text=https://www.cnord.ru/myalarm.html')
```

В таком виде работает